# Erro ao executar o emulador do Android Studio

Tags: java, android, android-studio, avd

Estou com um problema na hora de emular um device no android studio. Quando tento acontece o seguinte erro:

> 15:28:24 FileNotFoundException:
>   /home/henrique/.android/avd/3_2_HVGA_slider_ADP1_API_17.ini (Arquivo
>   ou diretório não encontrado)

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Depois de ter criado a AVD não aparece e quando clico pra emular aparece para criar uma.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Já verificou se realmente existe esse arquivo ou diretório no endereço indicado?

Comment: Isso que não entendo. Só tem uma arquivo dentro de .android/

Comment: Isso que não entendo. Só tem uma arquivo dentro de .android/ um arquivo chamado uid.txt, com esse conteúdo: 23a02592-9afb-4694-b798-fccd0956879a

Comment: Tente criar novamente uma maquina virtual e verifique onde ela está sendo configurada.

Comment: Esse diretório avd é onde encontra todas as máquinas virtuais criadas.

Comment: No caso ter que desinstalar o AVD e reinstalar normalmente?

Comment: Você criou uma máquina virtual certo?! Então, quando você cria um avd ele gera esse arquivo `.ini`. Pelo que parece, a ide não está encontrando esse arquivo. Por padrão ele deveria estar dentro desta pasta avd. O que estou dizendo é pra você tentar criar uma outra  avd com um nome mais acessível e fazer uma busca no seu HD pra ver onde foi parar esse arquivo.

Comment: Há, certo. Farei isso. Muito obrigado pelas dicas. Informarei se deu certo.

Comment: Não deu certo. Aparentemente ele não chega a criar a AVD.

Answer (score 1):

Pelo que percebemos, seu arquivo `.ini` não está dentro do diretório padrão como deveria estar. Então você tem que fazer uma verificação de onde realmente foi criado seu AVD (Android Virtual Devices).

Para mostrar os arquivos `.ini` e `.img` do AVD associado no disco, clique com o botão direito do mouse em um AVD e selecione *Show on Disk*. Ou clique em Menu  e selecione *Show on Disk*.

Você pode ler mais na própria documentação que diz como [Criar e gerenciar dispositivos virtuais](https://developer.android.com/studio/run/managing-avds.html?hl=pt-br).

Comment: @henrique-nascimento no link desta resposta, mostra como é possível criar e gerenciar dispositivos virtuais.

Comment: Então na verdade ele deixa criar a AVD, mas no caso quando se vai para a tela de gerenciar dispositivos virtuais, não tem nada. E quando procurei no HD não encontrei nada também relacionado a avd que tinha criado.

Comment: @HenriqueNascimento O problema então está na criação de um AVD. Vi ali no canto superior que tem atualizações a fazer no seu Android Studio. Tente atualiza-lo para a versão mais recente que talvez deva corrigir esse problema.

Comment: Vou atualizar, se não der certo ou se der posto aqui. Mas provavelmente vou desinstalar, é a terceira vez que tento instalar no ubuntu, desde sexta e toda vez da algum tipo de erro. Vou reinstalar em outra oportunidade. Quando tive windows em dualboot com ubuntu.

Comment: @HenriqueNascimento eu já passei muita raiva com esses tipo de coisa. Hoje eu uso Windows, mas gostaria de estar usando Linux mas já tive uns problemas grandes de perder bastante tempo e perder projetos. Por toda ruindade do Windows, ainda uso por causa de Photoshop e CorelDraw que sou viciado. Nas épocas que usei UBUNTU, migrei para o Inkscape, mas nunca, nem chegou aos pés dessas duas ferramentas maravilhosas (Photoshop e CorelDraw) hehe. Mas boa sorte ai!

Comment: kkk sei come é. Eu criei uma pasta avd dentro do diretório .android/ ficando assim: .android/avd. Agora mostra as AVD's no gerenciado. Porem ainda ta com um erro: